# Parsing XPath Query

Tags: xpath

I would like to receive the output:

```
10.62.197.125, 10.62.197.126, 10.62.197.127.
```

How do I make that happen? (Note that the code has been somehow manipulated due to customer restrictions).

```
<output arrayType="ns2:aaa[20]" type="ns2:aaa_array">
  <item type="ns2:bbb">
    <ip_addr type="xsd:string">0a2ef556</ip_addr>
    <hostaddr type="xsd:string">10.62.197.125</hostaddr>
    <subnet_name type="xsd:string">Test</subnet_name>
    <pool_id type="xsd:string">0</pool_id>
  </item>
  <item type="ns2:aaa">
    <ip_addr type="xsd:string">0a3c3c33</ip_addr>
    <hostaddr type="xsd:string">10.62.197.126</hostaddr>
    <subnet_name type="xsd:string">Test</subnet_name>
    <pool_id type="xsd:string">0</pool_id>
  </item>
  <item type="ns2:aaa">
    <ip_addr type="xsd:string">0a3a72c4</ip_addr>
    <hostaddr type="xsd:string">10.62.197.127</hostaddr>
    <subnet_name type="xsd:string">Test</subnet_name>
    <pool_id type="xsd:string">0</pool_id>
  </item>
</output>
```

Comment: XPath does not "produce output", it selects nodes. You will need the help of another programming language to turn those nodes into a string. Have you tried anything? If yes, what? If not, why not?

Comment: What version of XPath? If you can use 2.0, you can use [string-join()](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#func-string-join).

Comment: Well, I am using a tool from the company for producing the output or possibly select the proper nodes as you state. I have not tried anything yet as I have no idea how to script it. What I first tried to do was to strip the text up to and including "<hostaddr type="xsd:string"> and strip again after and including "</hostaddr> but that did only give me the first value as an output as I can't strip more values through the tool (more than one single value). Now, I would like to use a xpathExpression to get the output out of the xml code above.

Comment: The XPath expression you look for is very simple. XPath tutorials are plenty and readily available. What's keeping you from reading about XPath basics and trying things until you have something that works at least half-way? There are XPath testers available (like [this one](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath)) that you can use for a trial-and-error approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To get the elements:**
`/*/item/hostaddr/text()`

results in

```
10.62.197.125
10.62.197.126
10.62.197.127
```

**To get a string (supported by XPath 2.0+):**
`string-join(/*/item/hostaddr/text(), ', ')`

results in

`10.62.197.125, 10.62.197.126, 10.62.197.127`

**This means:**
Select the text in the hostaddr element in all item elements.

**Test:**
You can test this by going to a XPath tester, like [this](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html), paste your XML in Option 1, paste the expression in XPath expression field and press the test XPath button.

Comment: _the closest you can get with XPath is the node texts_ - unless the OP can use XPath 2.0 (`string-join(//hostaddr,', ')`).

Comment: Updated answer to reflect this @DanielHaley